# How to switch an NXT sensor port by a motor port?

Tags: nxt

Me and my partner are finishing up our robot for the RobotCup and we desperately need one more motor port. We will only use 3 sensor ports, so my question was if there was even the slight chance that we could switch one for the other.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible - sensor ports don't have the hardware to drive motors. That said, you can buy a motor multiplexer like [this one](http://www.mindsensors.com/index.php?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=134) to do the job for you, if competition rules allow this.